# kaiser filter coeffecients calculation

Tags: signal-processing

I want to calculate the coefficients of Kaiser FIR Filter. I have seen some implementation but they limit filter order to be less than 20, i dont want limit on this and maybe i can use order of 19 or 89 for experimentation.
I need some tool for this. Link below shows GUI of  tool (java applet) to provide filter coefficient calculation but applet is not available now.  Has any one got this or similar tool to share.

[This tool is nice with minimum inputs but unable to find it for download or online calculation](http://homepage3.nifty.com/ji3gab/figs/filter-design.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to MATLAB or a computer with MATLAB, you can use the [fdatool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fdatool.html) command that will open a new window and allow you to design filters according to your specifications.

Once MATLAB creates the filter, there are many functionalities to use, including one where you can extract the coefficients and view them.